# Hardcoded string with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to append the string "By - " with a value obtained from a property through ngModel i.e. `<textarea [(ngModel)]="book.Author"..>`and add it to a header `<h2>{{book.Title}}</h2>` in angular
so that it displays "Title By - Author". 
The data is being obtained through http api. I want the "By - Author" only when there is a value for Author in the text area.
How do I achieve this? I am new to angular.

Comment: So the text contains only 'Ttitel' until the http request comes back?

Comment: what happens if author name is null or empty?

Comment: @ Batajus - both Title and Author values are obtained from web api.
@ Shubham If author is null or empty it should just show the title value "By -" should be hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution could be to use Angular directives `*ngIf` in combination with `<ng-container>` in your header like so:

```
<h2>
{{book.Title}} <ng-container *ngIf="book.Author"> By - {{book.Author}}</ng-container>
</h2>
```

[ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

> doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Comment: A down-vote without explanation is not very helpful. Please provide constructive feedback if you feel my answer is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [ngModel] attribute binding with input event emitter. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbqub9